# rails url escape string "john.walter.name" failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, escaping

Does any could try to run this below code in your rails view <%=CGI::escape("john.walter.name" )%>

you will see, it does not escape anything, still "john.walter.name" .

if we run  <%=CGI::escape("john#walter#name" )%>

you will get john%23walter%23name

is it a bug , any workaround?

or "." is not needed to be escaped at all? I dont think so.

Comment: "I don't think so". Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

"." does not need to be escaped. For more info on what needs to be escaped see [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)